# How to Ceate Exit Icon in TitleBar Or Label Name in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-theme, android-titlebar

I want to put an exit icon or log out button near the label name or title bar, so if I am anywhere in my application I can get back to the main menu. I have searched similar question at Stackoverflow but don't understand the answers. Perhaps the problem is I'm new to Android programming

Could someone explain how to do this?

Comment: Do you mean sliding menu??

Comment: @Tarun No I Want Exit Icon In Title Bar. Like Facebook Have Log out Button....Sorry I Can't Upload Image Due To Reputation.

Answer (score 0):

In your xml you have to add the button like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/new_game"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_new_game"
          android:title="@string/new_game"
          android:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
</menu>
```

The android:icon will fix it.

Comment: OK I Have Get it but what is the code behind it in activity so that when button is pressed i can get back to my main menu.